Formulating hypothesis test on the relationship between weather and market movement
I am learning hypothesis testing and here is one of the exercises: Suppose you are given a set of cloud cover data indexed by date and the cloud amount could vary from 0% (perfectly sunny) to 100% (perfectly cloudly). You are also given a set of stock market data with the stock market closing price, again indexed by date. Formulate an appropriate hypothesis test that determines whether stock market movement is independent of the cloud amount.
So I have learnt that a hypothesis test should be a test on population parameter. I am having a bit of troubles trying to find the appropriate population parameter in this case. I have learnt anout Z-test, t-test, chi-square test. Any help is appreciated.

Given that you have no access to conditional probabilities, I think correlation/covariance is the easiest to establish, not independence. I may be wrong
